# Java scanner works from second time

Tags: java, console, java.util.scanner

I am trying to call a method after enter in console is pressed. Problem is method is called from second time I press enter. How can call my method after first Enter press?

```
public void read() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Press Enter to continue");
    try {
        System.in.read();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        this.win();
    }
}
public void win() {
    if (true) {
        this.read();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an unusual code structure, because the two functions call each other in what appears to be an infinite recursion. Is this intentional?

Comment: yes. Every time must hit enter to continue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code that waits for <kbd>Enter</kbd> to be pressed "steals" that character from the input stream before `Scanner` gets to see it. Hence, the first `'\n'` gets consumed by `System.in.read()` line.

When you call `scanner.hasNextLine()` for a `Scanner` based on the console, the code blocks to see if end-user enters a line or terminates the stream. The second `'\n'` is needed for the `hasNextLine` method to return.

You can fix this by removing the call to `System.in.read()`, and calling `getNextLine()` to consume the input before next call:

```
public void read() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Press Enter to continue");
    try {
        System.in.read();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        scanner.nextLine(); // Remove '\n' from the buffer
        this.win();
    }
}
```

Comment: problem is that I trigger another method2 and I want to back to method1(press any key) again and when Enter is pressed to go to method2

Comment: @TeodorKolev Calling `scanner.hasNextLine()` would block until Enter is pressed. You don't even need to check its return value.

Comment: I do not understand

Comment: I am trying to switch between two methods on enter press

Comment: In your current solution after first time it did not prompt again and waiting to press enter again

Comment: @TeodorKolev In method1 print `"Press Enter to continue"`, and call `scanner.hasNextLine()`. This would wait for the user to press enter. You can read `nextLine` if you wish to remove Enter from scanner's input. If you do that, the next call to `hasNextLine` will wait for `'\n'` in the input stream again.

Comment: @TeodorKolev Could you edit your code to show interaction between method1 and method2 that does not work? Add a comment line at the spot where something that you want to happen does not work as intended. It would be much easier to fix your code for method1 and method 2 than to write one from scratch.

Comment: @TeodorKolev try adding a call to `scanner.nextLine()`, like this: `if (scanner.hasNextLine()) { scanner.nextLine(); this.win();}`

Comment: Nope, my mistake. Please add it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `System.in.read();`. The `java.util.Scanner.hasNextLine()` method returns true if there is another line in the input of this scanner. This method may block while waiting for input.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Press Enter to continue");

        if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
             System.out.println("Victory!");
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, your code waits for user to press any key at two points. First at `System.in.read();` and then at `scanner.hasNextLine()`. That's why you need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key twice before `victory` gets printed on the console. Removing either `System.in.read();` or `scanner.hasNextLine()` from your code will fix the issue.

Comment: problem is that I trigger another method2 and I want to back to method1(press any key) again and when Enter is pressed to go to method2